# PHP - Removing commas from array

Tags: php, arrays, post

I'm trying to create some PHP that will perform a calculation from two sequences of input text.

If the user enters 9,8,2 in one input, and 5,2,3 in other it will perform a calculation.

Anyway, I've gotten very close but the calculation is showing commas and I'm not sure how to get rid of these commas from the array. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$first = $_POST['first'];
$second= $_POST['second'];

$maths = $first[0] * $second[0] + $first[0] * $second[1] + $first[0] * $second[2] + $first[0] * $second[3] + $first[0] * $second[4] + $first[0] * $second[5] + $first[1] * $second[0] + $first[1] * $second[1] + $first[1] * $second[2] + $first[1] * $second[3] + $first[1] * $second[4] + $first[1] * $second[5] + $first[2] * $second[0] + $first[2] * $second[1] + $first[2] * $second[2] + $first[2] * $second[3] + $first[2] * $second[4] + $first[2] * $second[5];
$result = "$first[0] * $second[0] + $first[0] * $second[1] + $first[0] * $second[2] + $first[0] * $second[3] + $first[0] * $second[4] + $first[0] * $second[5] + $first[1] * $second[0] + $first[1] * $second[1] + $first[1] * $second[2] + $first[1] * $second[3] + $first[1] * $second[4] + $first[1] * $second[5] + $first[2] * $second[0] + $first[2] * $second[1] + $first[2] * $second[2] + $first[2] * $second[3] + $first[2] * $second[4] + $first[2] * $second[5]";

echo "</br>";
echo "the question is $result";
echo "</br>";
echo  "the result is $maths ";
```

Comment: Are you in fact needing to [explode](http://php.net/explode) your POST params first?

Comment: @JonStirling I am quite new to PHP, I'm unsure of what explode is.  Would that ignore the commas for the input data?

Comment: Read the link and that will explain. Whether new or old, the PHP documentation is your friend :)

Comment: @JonStirling Yeah, I've been reading up as much as I can. Sometimes the terminology can be overwhelming and I get buried in detail. I've been working on PHP for a few weeks, usually I can eventually find a fix but this time I got really stuck.  Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that the example stated above actually returns the correct value, though as has been proved before I could well be wrong. Using the numbers above and the way in which you have shown the calculation that makes 135.. rather than 60.

```
    $sum=0;
    $question=array();

    $first=explode(',',$_POST['first']);
    $second=explode(',',$_POST['second']);

    for( $i=0; $i < count( $first ); $i++ ){

        $row=array();
        $tmp=array();

        for( $j=0; $j < count( $second ); $j++ ){
            $tmp[]='( '.$first[ $i ]. ' x '. $second[ $j ].' )';
            $row[]=$first[ $i ] * $second[ $j ];
        }
        $sum+=array_sum( $row );
        $question[]=implode( ' + ', $tmp );
    }
    echo 'The question is: [ ' . implode( ' ] + [ ', $question ).' ]<br />';
    echo 'Total: '.$sum;
```

Comment: Your code works much better, actually. The example above worked for me after I made a few other changes, however I was unable to add extra numbers. It did however fix my comma issue. I did get the correct answer, but I couldn't add more numbers as it just wouldnt do anything with those numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
$first = explode(',', $_POST['first']);
$second= explode(',', $_POST['second']);
```

Now you got two real arrays with the data like:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```